# Why won't my property set in cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I'm currently building my own MVC in ColdFusion 9 (cfscript) and for some reason I am having a little trouble in the Base Model that I have created.

```
    public function init(required itemName){
    var columns = {};
    var result = '';
    var type = '';
    var length = '';
    var key = '';
    var field = '';
    var allowNull = '';

    setModel(itemName);

    this.table = this.model.tableName();

    this.qdb = request.qwerkfactory.newQDB();
    this.qdb.init(tableName = this.table);
    this.qdb.getTableAttributes();
    this.result = this.qdb.execute().getResult();

    for(i = 1; i LT this.result.recordcount; i++){
        result = this.result;

        type = ReReplaceNoCase(result['type'][i], '[0-9()]', '', 'all');
        length = ReReplaceNoCase(result['type'][i], '[a-z()]', '', 'all');
        key = (len(result['key'][i])) ? result['key'][i] : false;
        field = result['field'][i];
        allowNull = result['null'][i];

        columns["#field#"] = {};
        columns["#field#"].type = "#type#";
        columns["#field#"].length = "#length#";
        columns["#field#"].key = "#key#";
        columns["#field#"].null = "#allowNull#";
    }

    setTableAttributes(columns); 

    return this.model;
}
```

This is my method that acts as a constructor method for my Model component. What it's doing is geting the table schema for a particular table and then it will return it to a model that inherits this base class. However, I have defined a property for the component called tableColumns, when I set it in a setter method:

```
    public function setTableAttributes(required struct attr){
    this.tableColumns = arguments.attr;
}
```

It sets it fine at this point, when I writeDump() this.tableColumns it returns the correct result. But when using the getter it says tableColumns is undefined in this. What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, QDB is my database abstraction layer for the framework which is what the reference is to in my code droplets.

Comment: When you say you are using a getter, are you saying that you have a function that returns `this.tableColumns` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is form your use of the `this` scope. Properties of CFCs are stored in the `variables` scope of the CFC..which is different than `this`.

Simply change your code above to use the `variables` scope instead of `this` scope and your getters will work as expected.